# Using jQuery's .add method

Tags: jquery

Either I am making a very silly mistake here, or there is a bug with jQuery's `.add` method. Most likely the former.

I am trying to implement a list of items that could be selected. Here's my [code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2weq2/).

The test case that is failing is the following:

1. Click the first element to select it.
2. Ctrl-click the second element to select it too.
3. Then click the third element (without `Ctrl`).

Now, I'd expect the first and second to be de-selected, I believe the implementation also does this. But the second one does not get de-selected.

Digging a little, it seems that the `.add` is actually not adding my elements to the jQuery object set and for the life of me, I can't figure out why.

Any suggestions on this? Or is this not the way the `.add` method is supposed to be used?

**Edit**: I know jquery-ui has a control for this kind of thing, but I have already evaluated it and it does not work for me. Thanks.

Comment: i think you should do `prevSelections.each(...)` to remove classes

Comment: @venimus there is no need to use `.each()` for that `prevSelections.removeClass('foo')` would suffice.

Comment: @venimus, Actually, jQuery methods act on all selected elements in its object set, so `.each` isn't necessary

Comment: it was just a first thought, but +1 for the simple implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.add` returns a new jQuery object, so you need to grab the value returned.

```
prevSelections = prevSelections.add(...);
```

Here's some other cleanup applied:

```
var ps = $(),
    clazz = 'selected';
$('#list').delegate('li', 'click', function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        ps = ps.add($(this).toggleClass(clazz));
    } else {
        if (ps.length) {
            ps.removeClass(clazz);
        }
        ps = $(this).addClass(clazz);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/mAPQA/

Comment: what do you mean, do you get an error? I don't have a mac, could you give more info?

Comment: Of course - my apologies. On Macs, `ctrl`-click is the same thing as right-click. So, instead of `ctrl`-click selecting additional items in the list, it just shows the context menu.

Comment: Oh! That's a very important piece of information for non-mac web devs like me. Thanks a ton for sharing. I'll research deeper :)

Answer (score 1):

[`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) constructs a new jQuery node set object.

Instead of

```
prevSelections.add($(this).toggleClass('selected');
```

[do](http://jsfiddle.net/2weq2/4/)

```
prevSelections = prevSelections.add($(this).toggleClass('selected');
```